# What technology can allow me to get a Databricks style interface for my Data Lake, but on-premise?

Tags: python, database, hive, databricks, apache-zeppelin

I am really happy with Databrick's "accessibility". One can simply click on the desired databases and navigate through the tables and inspect them. Then, one can display and save different notebook's (Zeppelin style notebooks) where one can query the databases by using different languages (pyspark, python, sql,r,..) or even manipulate the data with Python scripts and store the results that are going to be accessible within this same interface.

**These options and this intuitive interface are really nice to create a seamless experience to navigate through my Data Lake (to have a glimpse on the DB's and the tables without having to query through code for example) in the cloud, but I'd like to know what similar technology I could use on-premise?**

Here attached, two screenshots of Databrick's interface.
On the left-hand side the Zeppelin style notebooks are accessible through the "workspace" icon and the DB's are accessible through "Data":

[image: Notebook]
[image: DB]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Commercial version: Cloudera Data Science Workbench